# Dynamically update non-data property in custom AG Grid cell renderer

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I have a grid where I want to show an editor button in a column for each row, and a new item creator button outside the grid.

The business requirement is that all buttons must go into a disabled state when pressing either create or edit buttons.

I've created a custom cell renderer for the edit button with a property inside that controls the disabled state, but I don't know how to update the property from outside the context of the grid.

The only way I'm able to achieve the desired behavior is to pass the `isDisabled` state as a function to the cell renderer, wrapping the external value, and take advantage of Angular's way of handling expressions in tempaltes. In this case, Angular doesn't know how to deal with a non-deterministic value and just calls the `isDisabled()` function to infinity, and as I change the outside wrapped value, the cell will eventually also update.

[I've created a sample for convenience](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-n9fjgg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ag-grid-edit-renderer',
  template: `
  <button
  class="ag-edit-button"
  (click)="onClick()"
  [disabled]="isDisabled()"
>
  Edit
</button>`,
})
export class AgGridEditRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  private params: any;

  isDisabled = () => false; // this is a bad practice because Angualr needs to constantly evaluate its value

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.isDisabled = params.isDisabled;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  onClick() {
    this.params.clicked(this.params.data);
  }
}
```

I setup the grid with the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
  isDisabled = false;
  currentVal: number | string = 0;

  columnDefs = [ 
    { field: "id", 
      cellRendererFramework: AgGridEditRendererComponent, 
      cellRendererParams: { 
        isDisabled: () => this.isDisabled,
        clicked: (params) => this.openEdit(params.id)
      }
    }, 
    { field: "make" }, { field: "model" }, { field: "price" }
  ];

  rowData = [
    { id: 1, make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
    { id: 2, make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
    { id: 3, make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
  ];

  openNew() {
    this.isDisabled = true;
    this.currentVal = 'new item';
  }

  openEdit(val: any) {
    this.isDisabled = true;
    this.currentVal = val;
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.isDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

I tried various way to trigger a cell refresh, or row refresh via the `Grid API`, but nothing seemed to work.

I also thought about using an `Observable` or similar, but that seemed overkill.

This is a generic cell renderer, so I need to have a simple solution that works in most situation, so for example extending (polluting) the data model with special ephemeral properties is not really doable.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and had to explicitly call setColumnDefs() as mentioned here with updated columnDefs:

https://blog.ag-grid.com/binding-and-updating-column-definitions-in-ag-grid/

API Documentation for setColumnDefs:

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.2.0/javascript-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/

Adapted Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-ucrehf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to refresh it forcefully?

The issue you face is that ag grid won't refresh if the value of the cell didn't change, that's why you need to use `force: true`. Depending the version of ag grid this might be done in another way, but the idea is the same, you need to tell ag-grid to refresh cell despite the fact that value is didn't change.

```
    gridOptions.api.refreshCells({
      force: true,
      columns: ['id'], // colId of the column you want to refresh
    });
```

```
  columnDefs = [ 
    { field: "id",
      colId: 'id' // add this
      cellRendererFramework: AgGridEditRendererComponent, 
      cellRendererParams: { 
        isDisabled: () => this.isDisabled,
        clicked: (params) => this.openEdit(params.id)
      }
    }, 
    { field: "make" }, { field: "model" }, { field: "price" }
  ];
```

Also, you need to return `true` from the refresh callback

```js
export class AgGridEditRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  private params: any;

  isDisabled = () => false; // this is a bad practice because Angualr needs to constantly evaluate its value

  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {}

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.init(params);
  }

  // move initialization login to init and execute it both on refresh and agInit
  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    this.init(params)
    return true;
  }

  onClick() {
    this.params.clicked(this.params.data);
  }

  private init(params: any) {
    this.params = params;
    this.isDisabled = params.isDisabled;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

Why do think that function in template is a bad practice?
Your function just return boolean value, it does not have any computation logic, so you're fine.
The problem may arise when you have some kind of a loop or heavy logic in that function. But this also could be addressed by using `onPush` change detection to reduce amount of Change Detection checks.